# What preprocessing steps to be followed before image comparison?

Tags: python, scipy, scikit-image

For example I am trying to find the similarity between two images using `skimage - SSIM`. The code block will be as follows

```
from skimage.measure import compare_ssim as ssim
from skimage import io
from skimage.transform import resize

a = io.imread("http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/51PV4Dd8wAL._AC_UL246_SR190,246_.jpg",as_grey=False,dtype="float64")
b = io.imread("http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/914ZHE6JolL._UY500_.jpg",as_grey=False,dtype="float64")

a = resize(a,b.shape)
ssim(a, b,multichannel=True)
```

I got the similarity score as follows

```
0.21009350738786017
```

Although both the images are same where one images in slightly oriented , I am getting very really low scores for this comparisons. Am I missing any preprocessing steps here before I compute compare images. If so what are the things I should consider before comparing images.

Thanks In Advance !!

Answer (score 0):

Just resizing the image to zoom in/out to match the other image is always going to yield a structural difference. 
When you zoom out an image, some values are aggregated (think pixelation). While when you zoom in, values are again modified. Hence in both cases there is loss/aggregation of information in all channels.

This will always yield a structural difference.
Ssim is preferably used for originally  same size images.(not resized)